# Rails routing error on valid route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following in my routes file:

```
resources :timelogs do
  member do
    post :stop
  end
  collection do
    get :start
  end
end
```

which produces the following on 'rake routes' :

```
rake routes | grep stop
stop_timelog POST   /timelogs/:id/stop(.:format)       {:action=>"stop", :controller=>"timelogs"}
```

However, when posting a request to that URL I'm seeing:

```
Started POST "/timelogs/325/stop" for 188.220.17.64 at Wed Nov 24 02:22:22 -0800 2010
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/timelogs/325/stop"):
```

All of this looks like it should be working, however, it's not.  What could be the problem here?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081153/rails-routing-what-am-i-missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually when you are trying to send your form with exists resource (ticket) rails by default will send `PUT` request, so you should set `:method => :post` clear or change route from

```
post :resolve, :on => :member
```

to

```
put :resolve, :on => :member
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem with the routes you've pasted and have verified that they work for me in an scratch app.

```
Started POST "/timelogs/123/stop" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-11-24 11:49:25 +0000
  Processing by TimelogsController#stop as */*
  Parameters: {"a"=>"b", "id"=>"123"}
Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 60ms (Views: 59.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Perhaps something else in your routes.rb is in conflict here?