# Rails routing: What am I missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

My app has Tickets, and a ticket can be "resolved". I can POST via AJAX to the :resolve action with no issues, but I cannot POST via a normal HTML form. I get `No route matches "/tickets/321/resolve"`. Both the HTML form and the JS point to the same exact URL. What am I doing wrong?

Routes:

```
resources :tickets do
  post :resolve, :on => :member
end
```

Controller:

```
def resolve
  resource.resolved!

  respond_to do |wants|
    wants.html { redirect_to :back }
    wants.js
  end
end
```

Form:

```
= form_for(ticket, :url => resolve_ticket_path(ticket)) do |f|
  ...
```

Comment: Look into source of your HTML and check if `METHOD` of your form is `GET`. Then set `:method => :post`

Comment: small remark: if resolving of ticket is toggling boolean inside ticket model, so better to use `PUT` method

Comment: You catch an error as a response after submitting form? If so - the problem inside of controller's resolve action

Comment: There is a text field that's updated with a remark from the user; I just removed the related stuff for clarity.

Comment: Yes, the error is after submitting, but the logs show ActionController::RoutingError -- so it's not even hitting the action code. Remember that AJAX POSTing works fine with the same action.

Comment: just for experiment, change your route and try to submit then: `put :resolve, :on => :member`

Comment: OK, WTH. :put magically works. I could've sworn I tried that hours ago. Sigh. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Ok. The reason you can read below :)

Comment: But don't forget now to handle with AJAX if you've changed method

Comment: The issue was that I recently changed some code around and the POST was creating a "response" object that was associated with the Ticket. After I merged Ticket and the response object, the POST should've been updated to a PUT. Missed it in the refactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually when you are trying to send your form with exists resource (ticket) rails by default will send `PUT` request, so you should set `:method => :post` clear or change route from

```
post :resolve, :on => :member
```

to

```
put :resolve, :on => :member
```